# Tensorflow mix two multivariate distribution

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I would like to mix two multivariate distribution in tensorflow. For example:

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tfd = tfp.distributions

#mean,var,pi have the same shape(3,4).
mean = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.arange(12.0).reshape(3,4))
var = mean
dist = tfd.Normal(loc=mean,scale=var)
pi = tf.ones_like(mean)
mix = tfd.Mixture(cat = tfd.Categorical(probs=[pi,1-pi]),components=[dist,dist])
```

However, it got the error as follows:

> ValueError: Dimensions 2 and 3 are not compatible
>
> ValueError: Shapes (2, 3) and (3, 4) are not compatible

Can I mix two multivariate distribution in tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

Try if this solves your issue

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions 

#mean,var,pi have the same shape(3,4).
mean = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.arange(12.0).reshape(3,4))
var = mean
dist = tfd.Normal(loc=-1., scale=0.1)

pi = tf.transpose(tf.ones_like(mean))

mix = tfd.Mixture(cat = tfd.Categorical(probs=[pi/3,
                                               pi/3,
                                               pi/3]), 
                  components=[tfd.Normal(loc=mean,scale=var), 
                              tfd.Normal(loc=mean,scale=var), 
                              tfd.Normal(loc=mean,scale=var)]
                 )

mix.event_shape_tensor
```

output

```
<bound method Distribution.event_shape_tensor of <tfp.distributions.Mixture 'Mixture_11/' batch_shape=(3, 4) event_shape=() dtype=float64>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems that it does not work if the components contain only two distributions. I'm not sure why it happens.  `mix = tfd.Mixture(cat = tfd.Categorical(probs=[pi/2,pi/2]),components=[dist,dist])`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think it might be because your mean/var are not square matrices.

Comment: I think you are right. I found another solution for this. Instead of assigning the probability to `pi #shape(3,4)`, I assign it to `pi #shape(3,4,2)`. That means each element of the pi is a probability list eg. `pi[0][0] = [0.5,0.5]`. That works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

the trick is, it appears, that number of categories needs to be the last dimension in probs, this code works for me:

In:

```
mix = tfd.Mixture(cat = tfd.Categorical(probs=tf.stack([pi,1-pi],axis=-1)),components=[dist,dist])
mix
```

Out:

```
<tfp.distributions.Mixture 'Mixture' batch_shape=[3, 4] event_shape=[] dtype=float64>
```